# iOS - Zoom a view to show more its subviews

Tags: ios, zooming, timeline, libs

I want to zoom a view to show more its subviews.
For example, I have an event timeline, I want to zoom in/out timeline to show more/less events.

Can anyone suggest me some idea or libs?

Comment: This question, in its current format is too broad for SO QnA style.

Comment: you can use scrollview to zoom in and out on a view